# Best approach for separate styles per organisation in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a web application which will support multiple organisations. To keep things simple (as I don't have a lot of experience with MVC), I set up the custom routing like `site.com/organisation1`, `site.com/organisation2` etc.

Each organisation has to be able to choose their own colors, fonts and images on their page. The structure of the page and the inner workings of the application will be the same for each organisation.

**EDIT:** Organisations have to be able to create and style their page on-the-fly. No developer should be involved during this process.

I'm not sure as to what is the best approach to separate the different layouts. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd go for saving the org schema (colours, images etc.) into db, then creating a layout (master) page that uses that from organization model provided; then store organization in session and/or viewdata or model (depending on the number of users vs number of views) and then render the layout using the db retrieved pieces from an organization schema.

Comment: If the goal is separating layouts only, Mvc has layout.cshtml file so you may create Organization1Layout.cshtml and organization2.cshtml ...

Comment: @zaitsman I think I'll go with your solution. Had something like that in mind but wasn't sure how to style the page and send a model with it altogether. So what you are saying is for example giving the ViewBag a value for the background color and giving the model (data) as a parameter to the view, right?

Comment: @Sn0wBlind something like that. Depending on complexity you might want to only store the id or something and then retrieve model from httpcontext cache in the layout page and then repopulate the cache on app start and when organization style changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Have seperate layout for each organisation with specific styles like `organisation1_layout.cshtl, org2_layout.cshtml` in `Views/Shared` folder.

2.In `_Layout.cshtml`, determine organisation using URL/Routing details and set layout accordingly.

```
    @{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("Organisation1") {
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Org1.cshtml";
  }
   else
         {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Org2.cshtml";
}       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't that mean every time an organisation wants to "join", the developer has to create a new .cshtml file?